# Will the Docusign Integration key expire if I downgrade to a free plan?

Tags: docusignapi

I am currently using a docusign personal plan and I have integration keys setup in the account.**Will my integration keys work if I cancel my current plan and downgrade to the free one?** I only need the integration key for oauth of other docusign customers and not to send envelopes from my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using a free account for your DocuSign integrations. Free accounts cannot be used to go-live. After you are live, if you downgrade your account, we gracefully allow your app to continue working, but that can be changed at any time, so please contact your sales rep if you have any billing related questions.

If you are an ISV, or SI, and build apps for others, you should apply for a free partner account that can be used to promote integration keys. Check out how to get into this program :

https://www.docusign.com/partners